# Replacement of Alt-F2 (Gnome2) in recent KDE

Tags: kde, gnome2

I am currently on Ubuntu 10.10 and use Alt+F2 quiet a lot.

- I can enter commands
- I can enter paths

... and I have autocompletion for example to open /home/myuser I can type /ho/my

I will upgrade to the newest Ubuntu and do not like Unity etc. so I will switch to KDE.

Is there a replacement for that functionality in KDE?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. KDE has a replacement of it. It can also be accessed with the same shortcut - <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>. This is called [Krunner](http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Krunner).

Here is a screenshot

[image]

- [How to Open Krunner](http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Krunner#Open_KRunner)
- [Krunner tip & tricks](http://sciencekde.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/advanced-calculator-runner/)
- [Open files and folder with Krunner](http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Krunner#Open_files.2C_folders_and_devices)

Comment: Yes I saw the krunner, but it does not support autocomplete.